# Is there a way to implement sprintf's buffer allocation automatically?

Tags: c++

I want to use mysprintf () instead of sprintf () for automatic buffer size allocation.

Is there any problem with mysprintf()? Or can you recommend a better way?

```
char s[256];
sprintf(s, "%s-%s-%s", "abcdefg", "abcdefg", "abcdefg");
```

```
string s = mysprintf("%s-%s-%s", "abcdefg", "abcdefg", "abcdefg");
string mysprintf(const char* format, ...)
{
    int ret;
    char* buf;
    va_list ap;

    va_start(ap, format);
    ret = vasprintf(&buf, format, ap);
    va_end(ap);

    if (ret == -1) {
        return {};
    }

    string out(buf);
    free(buf);

    return out;
}
```

Comment: You are walking a path of great pain, trying to take all of the disadvantages of `sprintf` with little to show for it. Has anyone introduced you to [parameter packs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)? This will still be painful as all hell, but type safe.

Comment: Seems fine to me in principle (ignoring type safety), although strictly speaking it's not exception-safe; if `std::string`'s constructor throws, you've leaked memory.

Comment: Unless you want to learn about what's wrong with your existing code.

Comment: At the very least, you should wrap the allocated `buf` in a `std::unique_ptr` with a custom deleter to call `free()`

Comment: `vasprintf()` is GNU specific.   If your compiler is compatible with C99 - or supports the C99 standard library - you can use `vsnprintf()` to, (1) obtain a required buffer (2)  allocate a container (`std::string` or a `std::vector<char>`) of appropriate size and (3)  write the data directly to that container.    The benefit of this alternative is that all the allocations are cleanly deallocated (no need to call `free()` manually, and no opportunity to inadvertently not do so).

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to write your own function, use asprintf() instead.

But notice that it is a USE_GNU stuff.

Remember to free()

Comment: The point is to make a C++ wrapper around `asprintf` so that memory is managed via RAII.

Comment: Yes, @ jamedin's comment is my point.